# How to skip mvn dependencies set as property using Versions Maven Plugin?

Tags: maven, versions-maven-plugin

I am using Versions Maven Plugin to update my project versions.
I am using `mvn versions:use-latest-versions` to update the project dependency. But this disregards the versions set as property.

For instance, I have a pom defined as follows:

```
<properties>
     <vertx.version>3.5.0</vertx.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
     <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
     <artifactId>vertx-dependencies</artifactId>
-    <version>${vertx.version}</version>   <!-- This is replaced as below -->
+    <version>3.5.1</version>`             <!-- How to ignore this change? --> 
     <type>pom</type>
     <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

I want to update the version in the property and not in the dependency section. 
I can use `mvn versions:update-properties` to update the properties.

The problem is I want to use a combination of both the goals to update the properties.

Executing the 2 goals one after the other also doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The desired behavior can be achieved using `mvn versions:update-properties` and `mvn versions:use-latest-releases` in succession instead of `mvn versions:use-latest-versions`.